# How do I get a single picture from Facebook if I know the picture id?

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-fql

I want to get a picture from Facebook through the API from its picture id.
Has anyone else done this?

Answer (score 1):

Access it here:
http://graph.facebook.com/PICTURE-ID/picture

Sample:
http://graph.facebook.com/10150165453258827/picture

If an access_token is needed, you need to use an application and the Graph API.

http://graph.facebook.com/10150165453258827/picture?access_token=xxx

Here's the documentation on access_token and authentication:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/